# Bitwise Operator use

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, operators

while doing practice question,i encountered a code:

`private char[] a;`
`int newcap = ((a.length * 3) >> 1) + 1;`

where newcap is the new capacity of array,
Using `((a.length*3)+1)` will be sufficient too,but instead they have used a bitwise Operator.Why ??
I know the use of bitwise operator.
The code is from http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/Collection/ArrayList/Create_a_Char_Array_List_in_Java.htm

Comment: Okay,so `>> 1` it is the same as divide by 2,but how the use of bitwise operator is a performance optimizer instead of using divide by 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would not be the same, shifting to right of 1 bit is the same as doing a division by two.

For example, `10 >> 1 = 5`.

In your example, you multiply the length by 3, then divide by two and finally add 1 to the result so `"Using ((a.length*3)+1)"` would not be *"sufficient"*.

However, note that `((a.length*3) / 2 +1)` would do the same.

Note that you can also multiply by two with bitwise operator, but with left shift instead of right shift.

```
System.out.println(10 << 1);//print 20
```

Comment: Thanks,i never thought in that way.But then why they have used bitwise,i mean they could have simply used `10 / 2` ,i.e. Division operator

Comment: But i think using Bitwise operator >>1 will make some sense instead of using divide by 2,Because this code is written by a reputed and famous java developer

Comment: @user3423267 in term of micro-optimization `>>1` is faster then `/2`. Note that this does not apply to the multiplication. I'm curious, who is this *"famous and reputed"* developer ?

Comment: @user3423267 a counter question could be "why would you use a division?", and well, there isn't really any reason to.

Comment: Even i dont know his name,but he must be... ;) , btw,Thanks for answers

Comment: Just note that shifting, results only in integer number so 3>>1 = 1 etc. Multiplying with 0.5 is faster than dividing on 2 where fractional result is needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
<<n is often used instead of multiplication with (2 to the power of n)
>>n is often used instead of division by (2 to the power of n)
```

It is only a performance optimization for the processor which gives the same result.